# Google map API. Can't access by browser on mobile

Tags: google-maps, google-api

I tried to create a website use google map API and angularjs
http://realty.emotiv.media/RealtyPhone/Map.
I can access it with a desktop browser but when I use a mobile phone browser I see JavaScript errors. It doesn't display map on mobile.

How can I fix ?

In 'Google developers console' I check APi key, and set up it to http referer, I add my url http://realty.emotiv.media/RealtyPhone/Map#/discover/map-full 
and 
http://realty.emotiv.media/RealtyPhone/Map

Comment: It's working in android mobile with chrome browser

Comment: sorry, but my mobile use Chrome too, but it can't not display map

Comment: Some formatting changes to make it easier to read.

Comment: Can you please share what JavaScript errors you see when you use your mobile browser?

Comment: I verify my domain and now it can run Mobile

Answer (score 0):

I verify my domain and now it can run on Mobile